# Fancybox ajax loaded content "Onclick script" executes that many times on each fancybox load

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, fancybox

Using fancybox to load ajax content(html/javascript) in popup

> ```
> On the first click, ajax loaded js function in popup are working fine(single call).
> On the second click, ajax loaded js function are called twice in popup.
> On the third click, ajax loaded javascript function are called thrice and So on..
> ```

I check the javascript function by alert. It throws alert that many times equal to fancybox loaded on each click. I dont know why it is behave like that. I think i need to clear the previously loaded content in the fancybox.

```
$(".various").fancybox({
            modal           : false,
            showCloseButton : true,
            helpers         : {
                                overlay: {
                                    css: {
                                        'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
                                    }
                                }
                              },
            closeBtn        : true,
            closeClick      : false,
            maxWidth        : 1200,
            maxHeight       : 850,
            fitToView       : false,
            width           : '85%',
            height          : '85%',
            autoSize        : false,
            openEffect      : 'none',
            closeEffect     : 'none'
        });
```

Above the code i have used to call the fancybox ajax call on click a>href LINK TO "POPUP.HTML". Everything loads fine, except the javascript alert on fancybox popup window.

POPUP.HTML

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="popupGridTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd gradeX" id="row1">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center">4</td>
                <td class="center">X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even gradeC" id="row2">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center">5</td>
                <td class="center">C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd gradeA" id="row3">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center">5.5</td>
                <td class="center">A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even gradeA" id="row4">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
                <td>Win 98+</td>
                <td class="center">6</td>
                <td class="center">A</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- ONCLICK ON TBODY > TR CALLS THE JS FUNCTION THAT MANY TIMES EQUAL TO FANCYBOX POPUP -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var table = $('#popupGridTable').DataTable();
            $('body').on("click", '#popupGridTable tbody tr' ,function () {
                //alert('called that many times equal to number of click on fancybox popup');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#popupGridTable tbody tr').removeClass('row_selected');
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                parent.setInformation(id);
                return;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have used afterClose call to clear the html content. But still facing the same issue.

Please help me sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you need to provide more detailed information: your html, your javascript alerts, and eventually the php test code being loaded by ajax

Comment: I have added my popup html code. Please checkout.

Comment: You're clearly not including all of your code. You're talking about `AJAX`, but I don't see any `AJAX` in your code above. Your *issue* typically happens when a `.click()` event has been binded over and over and over again.

Comment: Hi @Marcus, you are right.. Onclick Event of '.various' class i have loaded the fancybox with url(POPUP.HTML)(not ajax). Please see the below code. i too have a thought, that it has  been binded again and again. If it is, then how do i overcome such issue.  

`code`<a class='various fancybox.ajax' href='popup.html'  >Click</a>

Comment: I don't think you can add js code in your called ajax page (which may conflict with js on the calling page)... I would rather set the js scripts on the calling page using delegated mode